# Converting the bash log file to CSV

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have some application log data on Linux server, which looks like this,

```
     2015-10-09 08:16:40,692 28456 INFO Demodb openerp.addons.service_logger.service_logger: 1 res.partner.fields_view_get ([], {'view_id': 127, 'toolbar': False, 'context': {'
     lang': 'en_US', 'tz': 'Europe/Brussels', 'uid': 1, 'active_model': 'res.partner', 'params': {'action': 60}, 'search_default_customer': 1}, 'view_type': 'search'}) 
     2015-10-09 08:16:40,701 28456 INFO Demodb openerp.addons.service_logger.service_logger: 1 res.partner.fields_view_get ([], {'view_id': 128, 'toolbar': True, 'context': {'l
     ang': 'en_US', 'tz': 'Europe/Brussels', 'uid': 1, 'active_model': 'res.partner', 'params': {'action': 60}, 'search_default_customer': 1}, 'view_type': 'kanban'})
```

I want to output this into csv format,(Basically from '([]' it can be a batch)

```
     2015-10-09,08:16:40,701,28456,INFO,Demodb openerp.addons.service_logger.service_logger:,1,res.partner.fields_view_get,([],{'view_id': 128,'toolbar': True,'context':,{'l
     ang':'en_US','tz': 'Europe/Brussels', 'uid': 1, 'active_model': 'res.partner', 'params': {'action': 60}, 'search_default_customer': 1}, 'view_type': 'kanban'})
```

Any input would be helpful,

Comment: Does the sequence "([]" is something fixed in every line of the log ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. In your example you replaced _some_ (though not all) of the spaces in the input lines by commas. What's the rule behind? Which columns do you want to have? What do you want to do with the commas in the input lines?

Comment: @ Avihoo Mamka: yes the sequence is same

Comment: @ Georg P.  I want to make use of every field separated by space as column, and at the end of the line when the special characters were present, they can be in one column or seperate columns seperated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replaces all whitespaces with commas until the first occurance of `([]`:

```
sed -e 'h;s/.*(\[\]//;x;s/\s\+(\[\].*//g;s/\s\+/,/g;G;s/\n/,([]/'
```

Explanation:

```
h                 # copy line to hold
s/.*(\[\]//       # remove everything before ([]
x                 # swap unchanged line back from hold, put part after ([] to hold
s/\s\+(\[\].*//g  # remove everything after ([]
s/\s\+/,/g        # do work, that is change spaces to commas
G                 # glue the two parts together, with a newline inbetween
s/\n/,([]/        # put the ([]-marker back between the two parts
```